# How to access TFS server thru a proxy with authentication?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, proxy

I am trying to access the TFS server of Codeplex thru a proxy that requires authentication and all I get is a 407.

I can navigate using the VS2010 browser and get Nuget packages so I know that the proxy is correctly configured but whenever I try to add the new TFS server I get a 407.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer (even when I do not get why it is so difficult):

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rido/archive/2010/05/06/how-to-connect-to-tfs-through-authenticated-web-proxy.aspx

Hope it helps to somebody

Comment: Even when now I can connect it always says that I have a wrong password ... :S